# if <a> is last child execute code

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have some code which links to 2 different pages. When you are on one page the other one is a link. eg

```
<div id="options">
<a href="#">other</a>
<p>current</p>
</div>

<div id="options">
<p>current</p>
<a href="#">other</a>
</div>
```

I want to execute an if statement if a is the last child but not sure of the correct syntax?
eg

```
if {/* #options a is last child*/}
{
     alert("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if an element matches a pseudo-selector by using the [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function:

```
if ($('#options a').is(':last-child')) {
  alert('hello');
}
```

It ends up being pretty readable.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/acWUT/**

Answer (score 2):

Well first of all you have two divs with the same `options` id -- that won't work at all.

But in general, to get the last a on the page, you could do:

```
var lastA = $("a:last")[0];
```

and then compare that in side your click handler:

```
if (lastA === this) 
{
     alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: thanks, understand about the ids but they are actually on different pages so on one page the <a> is first and the other the <a> is last. but your soloution will work well.